# QTimeEdit C++ delete padding

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, edit, qtime

I want to delete an undesirable padding on a QTimeEdit widget. Here is an example of my problem.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I succeeded to solve my problem, it was the border. So with a setStyleSheets it's ok !

Comment: OK great. I posted it as an answer, so others can refer to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `setStyleSheet` function.

See [Customizing Qt Widgets Using Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html) for reference.